# sending multiple mail using php using swift mailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am using swift-mailer to send email to user. I have implemented it and it works well. But I have different body for different mails, ie i need to include the ID, Name , address in the mail which is taken from the database. I was thinking of using a loop for this. But many of article shows its not a good practice to send the mail in loop. I use this [helpful tutorial](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) as reference. Is there any better way for this, If loop is to be used how could i implement this. I dont have much experience in php, I am basically a jsp developer.

**My CODE**

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mysite.net', 25)

  ->setUsername('me@mysite.net')
  ->setPassword('me123456')
  ;

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
->setFrom(array('me@mysite.net' => 'My Name'))
->setTo(array('name1@mysite.net', 'name2@mysite.net'))
->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);


?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sending email in a loop is not a good practice, because you could be treated as a spammer by your SMTP provider.
You should have a look into [*Decorator* plugin](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#decorator-plugin) for Swift mailer.

Comment: isnt decorator plugin also sending it in a loop? a single email for every recipient?

Comment: You're right Gigala. Decorator plugin will also send multiple emails. As a workaround to SMTP restrictions, there are also *AntiFlood* or *Throtter* plugins.